# Aqua Data Studio - Shortcuts for Autocomplete

Tags: sybase

When the autocomplete listbox/dropdown is displayed in Aqua Data Studio, you have to hit enter in order for the current hightlighted item to complete the identifier. Is there a way that I can hit the tab key to autocomplete instead? This is the default behavior for Visual Studio and I cannot find the keyboard shortcuts editor in Aqua Data Studio.

It would also be nice if while the autocomplete listbox is visible if the Home and End keys would go to the beginning or the end of the line instead of the top or the bottom options of the autocomplete listbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto File->Options->Key Mappings.
Select your Active KeyMap.
Under Keymap Settings, Goto General -> Query:Auto Complete and Select it.
Under Shortcut, click on the button Edit and you can change to suite your need.

Make sure there are no conflicts.
[image]

Comment: awesome, I've moved jobs so long ago that I don't use ADS anymore and can't test it, so I'll give you an upvote, if I see another upvote I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Look in the preferences for "keybindings"/"hotkeys".